Handling authentication with exceptions in Express
I'm implementing api security using JWT for my app. The app is very large already, so I'm hoping to avoid going and adding middleware directly to many routes. The majority of my routes need the userId in the query params to match the user who's token is in the header. A minority of routes have broader access rules, such as can also be accessed by the user's friend, etc.
I've thought of a few ways to achieve this, but none are totally satisfying. Is there a canonical way to apply stricter access control at a global level and then except certain routes from this access control?
The options I've already come up with, for reference:
Option 1: for strictly guarded routes, I get rid of the userId parameter and instead attach the userId to the request object during authentication. This, by default, makes it so each route can only operate on the authenticated user. I then can have allow a userId param on routes with broader access rules (like I also a user to be able to pull info about friendUserId) and apply the bespoke middleware directly to those routes. This is fairly elegant once implemented, but less than ideal to refactor because it requires a LOT of manual writing of code, even if it is only a line or two per route front and backend.
Option 2: globally apply the auth middleware in main with a conditional that checks for the routes with different access rules and selectively applies different middleware. Downside: decouples auth middleware from the routes for routes that require exceptions.
Option 3: directly apply each relevant middleware to each route. Also requires writing a lot of code.
